# Sweet alert 2 multiple checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, popup, sweetalert

I'm using this "sweet alert 2", I I need of multiple checkbox,
In documentation there is 'input-radio' option with multiple choice, but only single choice for checkbox option.

Is there possibily to use this script with checkbox multiple choice?

```
swal({
  title: 'Select color',
  input: 'radio',
  inputOptions: {
    '#ff0000': 'Red',
    '#00ff00': 'Green',
    '#0000ff': 'Blue'
  }
})
```

thanks

Answer (score 10):

It is not supported per se, but you can easily achieve that by writing your own HTML:

```
swal({
    title: 'Multiple checkbox inputs',
    html: `
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox1">
                    checkbox1
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox2">
                    checkbox2
                </label>
            </div>
    `,
    focusConfirm: false,
    preConfirm: () => {
        console.log('Is checkbox1 checked:' + document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked);
        console.log('Is checkbox2 checked:' + document.getElementById('checkbox2').checked);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm at a loss when trying to get the inputOptions Promise to play well with the html, or when trying to return the content of the checked checkboxes... could you please expand on your example?